# How to zip a folder on server using vb .net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, zip, directory

I am creating a button, When user click on button than I want to zip a folder and download it.

My code work perfect on local host but when I move it to server than I get an error.

**Here is the error:**

```
Server Error in '/myapp' Application.
Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Below you will find my code for zip and downloading folder. I have also added a system.io.compression as a reference.

**aspx.vb code:**

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

' Inorder to use 'ZipFile', you first have to 'Add reference'
' Right Click project > Add Reference > Browse > "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\..." > ok

Partial Class myclass
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click

    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\user\dave\desktop\MyFolder"

    ' Create Zip folder
    Dim TempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".zip"
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderPath, TempFile)

        ' Download Zip folder
        Response.Buffer = False
        Response.Clear()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Cases.zip")
        Response.ContentType = "Application/zip"
        Response.TransmitFile(TempFile)
        Response.End()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have hardcoded the folder path:

```
Dim folderPath As String = "C:\user\dave\desktop\MyFolder"
```

So here are a couple of things that you might check:

- This folder actually exists on the server on which you deployed the application
- The identity under which your Application Pool runs has read access to this folder

To pinpoint the issue you could simply follow the suggestion in the error message and enable verbose error output in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```